# All GET methods are working fine but only POST methods show error 405 The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-405

I'm using laravel 8, all GET methods are working fine but only POST methods show error

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

It only occurs for API routes.

API ROUTE

```
//creates new user.
Route::post('/create', [AuthController::class, 'createNewUser']);
```

```
public function createNewUser(Request $request)
    {
      
       $MyUser = MyUser::create([
        'uuid' => $request['uuid'],
        'uname' => $request['uname'],
        'uemail' => $request['uemail'],
        'uphone' => $request['uphone'],
        'udob' => $request['udob'],
        'utoken' => $request['utoken'],
    ]);
    $response['user'] = $MyUser;
    return response()->json($response, 201);
}
```

I have tried all cache, routes commands which laravel offers, all API side POST method routes not working and throwing error 405, while GET routs are working fine. on the other hand POST routes on web.php are working.

Comment: do you have a route with the same path? like: Route::get('/create', yourmethod)

Comment: no, it was working before now it shows 405 method not allowed error, all API side POST requests are not working but GET methods are working just fine

Comment: Can you share the code in which your making the post request?

Comment: the easiest method to debug is to check all the routes generated for this path using `php artisan route:list --path=create` and check if there is a route for the POST method in the list or not for this path. If there is no path for this then the issue lies in your api.php file

Comment: since this is an API call (ajax, fetch, etc.) Did you add method `POST`?

Comment: It would help if you also add the ajax/fetch you used to consume API

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that you include `@csrf` token within your form tag. And share your html code.

Comment: It is not a csrf token error. and it is good to ask for more information in comments and not post an answer

Comment: Its an API call

Comment: @MohammadhosseinFereydouni Users need 50 rep to comment. But I agree: if the question needs clarification it's better not to answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).